# REDUX: Dispatch is not update the store

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, react-redux, redux-toolkit, web-ext

I am working on a project that produces a chrome extension. I am trying to dispatch function in popup.tsx. However not dispatching. My store does not update. The same code works in background page. What can I do that? What could be the problem?

Here is my popup.tsx:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (
      !ip4Cache.hasOwnProperty(hostname) ||
      !geoIPcache.hasOwnProperty(hostname)
    ) {
      console.log('cachede yok')
      checkLookup([hostname]).then((res) => {
        setIp4(res.data['ip4'][hostname])
        dispatch(addIP4(res.data.ip4)) //I also tried store.dispatch in here
       
      })
    }
  }, [hostname])
```

Here is my store:

```
let sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const localStorage = createLocalStorage()
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: localStorage,
}

const reducers = combineReducers({
  ip4: ip4Reducer,
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducers>

const createPersistReducer = (config) => persistReducer(config, reducers)

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: createPersistReducer(persistConfig),
  middleware: [sagaMiddleware],
})
export const persistor = persistStore(store)

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

wrapStore(store, { portName: 'bla' })
```

And the last one, IP4 slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const ip4Slice = createSlice({
  name: 'ip4',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    addIP4: (state, action) =>
      (state = new Object({ ...state, ...action.payload })),
  },
})
export const { addIP4 } = ip4Slice.actions
export default ip4Slice.reducer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  reducers: {
    addIP4: (state, action) => {
      // either:
      Object.assign(state, action.payload);
      // or 
      return { ...state, ...action.payload }
    }
  },
```

Please give a read to the [Writing Reducers with Immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers) documentation page, especially to [Resetting and replacing state](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state).

Quoting the most important part:

> A common mistake is to try assigning `state = someValue` directly. This will not work! This only points the local state variable to a different reference. That is neither mutating the existing state object/array in memory, nor returning an entirely new value, so Immer does not make any actual changes.

Comment: I wanna ask another thing. When I use toolkit with webext-redux, proxy(popup) store not updating with wrap(background) store simultaneously in the first render. What could be the problem? Does useSelector not realize change of the state in the first render ?

Comment: @CerenKeklik that should be it's own question - and I really don't know an answer.